# Function to combine columns after a merge in R

Tags: r, merge

I would like to combine the columns after merging two dataframes. Right now, I am writing ifelse statements to get a unified column for each variable.  I would like a function to chose what data frame (i.e. x) should overwrite the other column.

```
df$source<-ifelse(df$source.x=='',df$source.y,df$source.x)
df$id<-ifelse(df$id.x=='',df$id.y,df$id.x)
df$profile_url<-ifelse(df$profile_url.x=='',df$profile_url.y,df$profile_url.x)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is just a bit unclear... For the above columns, you want to have df take on the values from y iff x is a blank string, otherwise take on the values from x?

Comment: How do you do your merge? can you give the context? and  please provide a reproducible example .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should hopefully do it.  (note, hasn't been tested as there's no sample data)

```
fixedColumn <- function(colm, myDF, keepx=TRUE) { 
  x <- myDF[[paste0(colm, ".x")]]
  y <- myDF[[paste0(colm, ".y")]]

  if(keepx)
    return(ifelse(x=='', y, x))
  # else  
  ifelse(y=='', x, y)
}

# columns that need fixing.  Don't include the suffixes
cols <- c("source", "id", "url")

# fix the .x columns
df[, paste0(cols, ".x")]  <- sapply(cols, fixedColumn, df)

# delete the .y columns
for (cc in paste0(cols, ".y"))
  df[[cc]] <- NULL
```

Using @agstudy's sample data:

```
> df
  Row.names id.x source.x url.x
1         1    2        2     3
2         2    3        1     3
3         3    3        1     2
4         4    3        2     2
5         5    3        2     2
```

Comment: +1; Might be a little faster to just do this: `x <- myDF[[paste0(colm, ".x")]]; x[x==''] <- myDF[[paste0(colm, ".y")]][x=='']`

Comment: but here this code will not work I think! "colm" is missing in your sapply, isn'it?

Comment: @agstudy, good catch, thanks!  I fixed the `sapply` statement and the function definition to match.

Comment: @Dwin, great suggestion.  I left the assignment to `y` in there simply to allow for the option of keeping either column as the dominant.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta what is myDF here? You can use my data to test your code.

Comment: Thank you @agstudy, I've used your data and cleaned up some errors in my code

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this step of swapping columns , you can use SQL via the `sqldf` package to swap columns (and if your real problem involves merges that can be done at the same time). Using `CASE` ... `WHEN` syntax you write the same if/else logic we have:

```
library(sqldf)
colnames(df) <- gsub('[.]','_',colnames(df))
sqldf(" SELECT 
             CASE  url_x    WHEN '' THEN url_y    ELSE url_x END as url ,
             CASE  source_x WHEN '' THEN source_y ELSE source_x END as source,
             CASE  id_x  WHEN '' THEN id_y ELSE id_x END as id 
      FROM df")
```

**Reproducible Example**

We test it with a reproducible example:

```
# create some data
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- matrix(sample(c('a','b','d',''),3*5,rep=T),ncol=3)
df2 <- matrix(sample(c('c','b','','a'),3*5,rep=T),ncol=3)
colnames(df1) <- c('id','source','url')
colnames(df2) <- c('id','source','url')
df <- merge(df1,df2,by=0)   

# run
library(sqldf)
colnames(df) <- gsub('[.]','_',colnames(df))
sqldf(" SELECT 
             CASE  url_x    WHEN '' THEN url_y    ELSE url_x END as url ,
             CASE  source_x WHEN '' THEN source_y ELSE source_x END as source,
             CASE  id_x  WHEN '' THEN id_y ELSE id_x END as id 
      FROM df")

 url source id
1   d      d  a
2   d      a  d
3   b      a  d
4   a      d  d
5   b      d  c
```

where `df` is :

```
Row_names id_x source_x url_x id_y source_y url_y
1         1    a        d     d    a        b     a
2         2    d        a     d    b        b      
3         3    d        a     b    b        c     a
4         4    d        d          c        c     a
5         5             d     b    c        c     c
```

**Using a helper function**

**(1)** If we have many of these then we might want to use a helper function which makes use of `fn$` from the gsubfn package that implements quasi-perl style string substitution:

```
xy <- function(s) {
    fn$identity("case $s_x when '' then $s_y else $s_x end as $s")
}

fn$sqldf("select `xy('url')`, `xy('source')`, `xy('id')` from df")
```

**(2)** or do it this way -- which stores the SQL statement into `s`:

```
s <- fn$identity("select `xy('url')`, `xy('source')`, `xy('id')` from df")
sqldf(s)
```

**More Info**

See the [sqldf home page](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) and for `fn$` see the [gsubfn home page](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com).